# How do I change the table and cell backgrounds to custom images in Interface Builder and xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

How do I change the basic table to custom images in Interface Builder and xcode?

Interface builder provides a boring white background for each cell.  I want it to look more custom.

I want to change that into something like this:

[image: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=51ufwg&s=6]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it all in interface builder and there's quite a lot of documentation on how to acheive this. I'll give you a few leads you can follow on your own:

1. The tableView background can only be set to a solid color or transparent, so if you want a gradient or an image background the best way would be to set the tableView.backgroundColor to [UIColor clearColor]. To actually create the background you can use a UIImage and place the table view above it. Make sure not to use UITableViewController and just use a UIView and add an UIImage to it and a UITableView.
2. The cells of the table can be created in interface builder or in code. In interface builder you'll find in the library a table view cell which you can customize. Google on creating UITableViewCell from NIBs